# How can I convert a plain text list to a python 3 list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, syntax, python-3.6

I would like to take a list of names and put them into a python list with the correct syntax. How could I do this? Because otherwise I would have to go through and put in quotes and commas everywhere and I am dealing with long lists.

For example if I had:

```
list = [
name
name1
name2
name3
name4
name5
]
```

How could I change those names to strings without doing each one individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- read the plain text from a file then split by \n

2- use this website: https://delim.co/#
in the converter settings you could add quotes

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and split on the newline characters (`\n`). `split()` will return an array of names:

```py
>>> x = """name
... name1
... name2
... name3
... name4
... name5
... """

>>> names = x.split('\n')
>>> print(names)
['name', 'name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name5', '']
```

Comment: This does not make a list. The variable is still assigned to a string.

Comment: I've updated the example to explicitly create a list, thanks!